# Able to focus input behind react navigation transparent modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I implemented an error modal using the example in the link below:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transparent-modals

The modal works fine, except that I am able to focus input when the modal is open, the behavior I wouldn't expect:

[image]